# How to get field type name?

Tags: c#, reflection

How can I get the type of a field in reflection?
I have already tried `FieldInfo.Name` and some other options with no success.

Suppose I have `int x = 5;`. How can I get the `"System.Int32"` or `"int"` string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want is [FieldInfo.FieldType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo.fieldtype.aspx).

If you want the full typename, use;

```
myFieldInfo.FieldType.FullName
```

Comment: Thanks, well I come from java and this is a little confusing,because in java all values you need have getters, so you look in the getters list.
In C# sometimes properties sometime get methods, a little bit head ache..

Answer (score 0):

```
string type = x.GetType().FullName;
```

type will be: `"System.Int32"`

Comment: In reflection you don't have access to variable name while iterating on fields.

Answer (score -1):

Use the GetType method - `x.GetType().Name;`

Comment: In reflection you don't have access to variable name while iterating on fields.